# Passing information from a collection view to a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

Right now I have a table view that is an extension of a collection view.

Here is a picture of the storyboard. 
[image]

The main premise of the app is similar to Apple Maps. I would like for a collectionView cell to be selected and then for the viewController to display a tableView that has all of the respected items from that category.

Here is my code for the collectionView.

```
 class ContentViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

let imageArray = [UIImage(named: "image 1"), UIImage(named: "image 2"), UIImage(named: "image 3")]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.mapIconImage.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.mapIconLabel.text! = imageNameArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowTableViewPlaces", sender: self)
}

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var mapIconImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var mapIconLabel: UILabel!

}
```

Here is the code so far for the tableView.

```
import UIKit

struct PlacesInTableView {
var name: String

init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
}
}

class MapItemsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var image1InTableView = [PlacesInTableView(name: "place 1"),
    PlacesInTableView(name: "place 2"),
    PlacesInTableView(name: "place 3")
]

var image2InTableView = [PlacesInTableView(name: "place 1")
]

var image3InTableView = [PlacesInTableView(name: "place 1"),
    PlacesInTableView(name: "place 2")
]
```

When a collection view is selected, I would like all of the locations in that respected category to occupy the contents of the tableview. How would I go about passing data from the collection view cell to a new tableView?

Comment: It's unclear how the *respected items from that category* are related to the data source array of the collection view. The code contains an array of images and an unknown `imageNameArray`. By the way using multiple arrays as data source is very bad practice and strongly discouraged.

Comment: Your explanation of the problem is not clear. For example, " display a tableView that has all of the respected items from that category". What do you mean "category"? You only mentioned collection view. How is that related to category? What do you mean "respected items" (from the category)? Can you give an example of a category and "respected items"?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you wanna pass the `name` value to the `MapItemsTableViewController` ?

You can override prepare function :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let viewController = segue.destination as! MapItemsTableViewController

    viewController.name = // Data can input here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

add storyboard id for table vc "MapItemsTableViewController" and add below code in ContentViewController

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MapItemsTableViewController") as? MapItemsTableViewController {
            vc.imageCate = indexPath.row
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

and then you can implement as below for MapItemsTableViewController

```
class MapItemsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var imageCate:Int?
    var image1InTableView = [PlacesInTableView(name: "place 1"),
                             PlacesInTableView(name: "place 2"),
                             PlacesInTableView(name: "place 3")
    ]

    var image2InTableView = [PlacesInTableView(name: "place 1")
    ]

    var image3InTableView = [PlacesInTableView(name: "place 1"),
                             PlacesInTableView(name: "place 2")
    ]

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if imageCate == 0 {
           return image1InTableView.count
        }
        else if imageCate == 1{
            return image2InTableView.count
        }else if imageCate == 2{
            return image3InTableView.count
        }else{
            return 0
        }
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        if imageCate == 0 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = image1InTableView[indexPath.row].name
        }
        else if imageCate == 1{
            cell.textLabel?.text = image2InTableView[indexPath.row].name
        }else if imageCate == 2{
            cell.textLabel?.text = image3InTableView[indexPath.row].name
        }else{

        }
        return cell
    }

}
```